# SonarQube MSBuild version warning

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, teamcity

I am running a C# build within teamcity which includes a step to analyze my code with Sonar.

However, I always get the warning within the sonar build logs.

```
INFO  - SonarAnalyzer.Scanner needs to be executed: true
        ***********************************************************************************
WARN  - *                 Use MSBuild 14 to get the best analysis results                 *
WARN  - * The use of MSBuild 12 or the sonar-scanner to analyze C# projects is DEPRECATED *
WARN  - ***********************************************************************************
```

Now i know that the project does not use MSBuild 12, and the first line in the snippet suggests that the issue is because `sonar-scanner` is been used.

How do I avoid the use of sonar scanner, and use MSBuild 14?

The following are the versions of my software:

```
Teamcity version 10.0.4
SonarQube version 6.2
Sonar C# plugin version 5.5.2.537
sonar-plugin for teamcity compiled from source as of 4th Jan 2017
```

Does the TeamCity Sonar plugin only use sonar-scanner or is it something else i can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SonarQube TeamCity plugin is a community one, which seem to use the SonarScanner directly. This is not ideal, because .NET projects can have complex build setups and the SonarScanner in itself is not able to process the various msbuild targets. .NET projects should be analyzed by the [SonarQube Scanner for MsBuild](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild), which delegates the project structure processing to MsBuild itself.

We don't have native integration with TeamCity, but that shouldn't stop you from using the Scanner for MsBuild. It's a [simple command line application](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+the+Command+Line), so you can call the `begin` and `end` steps in a TeamCity Command Line build step.

BTW, you see the msbuild12 warning, because the SonarScanner only runs a file by file analysis contrary to the Scanner for MsBuild, which uses whichever msbuild you specify. In case of MsBuild14 you benefit from all the goodies of Roslyn, and in case of MsBuild12 we fall back to the file by file analysis.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, I have installed and ran the command line application as you suggested however I am getting the error `SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects` and the suggested possible causes are not relevant. Where can i find the sonar logs for more information to debug with?

Comment: Can you make sure that you navigate to the solution folder before running the Scanner for MsBuild. The logs and most of the collected data is in a `.sonarqube` folder next to your solution. I suspect that you start the Scanner for MsBuild from one folder, and then navigate to your solution and start the build there.

Comment: I do not move folder at all, when i look in `.sonarqube` there is an `out` folder that only contains files, ProjectInfo.log and summary.md neither any use

Comment: Do you also have the bin and conf folders? Also is there any project specific folder in the out folder?

Comment: Can you run this analysis on your local machine from the command line (just to take TeamCity out of the picture)? You can follow the instructions here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+the+Command+Line

Comment: I have only been doing it on command line, team city is not involved in this case. I have just realized that I am using MSBuild 15 with VisualStudio 2017, Is sonar compatible with that yet?